# unexpected result when comparing numpy arrays with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When comparing 2 numpy arrays of different sizes I would expect either a boolean array based on broadcasting or an error to be raised.  Sometimes I just get False, as if its comparing them as objects.

In the following I would expect that if `-` fails, so does `==`:

```
In [18]: a = np.zeros((2,7,5))

In [19]: b = np.zeros((2,7))

In [20]: a == b
Out[20]: False

In [21]: a - b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a5f966a4b1f4> in <module>()
----> 1 a - b

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,7,5) (2,7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a-b` fails because automatic broadcasting occurs on the left, not the right.

```
np.zeros((2,7,5))-np.zeros((2,7))[:,:,None]
```

works

```
np.zeros((2,7,5))==np.zeros((2,7))[:,:,None]
```

and the equality test works element by element.

But as `Kasra` notes, in `a==b`, the element by element comparison will fail.  Clearly the two arrays are not equal.  Returning `False` is consistent with other Python uses of `==` (`.__eq__` method).  I don't know if the `numpy` developers even considered the alternative of returning a `ValueError`.

Consider what Python returns when comparing strings and lists:

```
'two'=='three'
[1,2,3]==[1]
'string'==['l','i','s','t']
```

I can't think of a case where `__eq__` returns an error instead of `False`.  But you might be able to code your own class that way.

Python documentation for `__eq__` says:

> A rich comparison method may return the singleton NotImplemented if it does not implement the operation for a given pair of arguments. By convention, False and True are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call bool() on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

`numpy` follows this - returning a boolean array if possible, `False` otherwise.

```
bool(np.zeros((2,7,5))==np.zeros((2,7))[:,:,None])
```

produces an error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

which is the root of a frequent SO question.

Comment: I am thinking that if i want a ValueError to be thrown when broadcasting is not possible, i should `a - b == 0`

Comment: I do use `==` when testing alternative ways of generating integer arrays.  But `allclose` is better if they are floats.  `== aScalar` is also common as a mask.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic operators on arrays apply elementwise. A new array is created and filled with the result, and if the arrays do not have same shapes python will raise a `ValueError` to notify you about the problem,as its an Arithmetic Error.

But for `==` python returns a `bool` value and its possible that you want to compare 2 arrays together and get a `bool` value (even if they have not a same shape),so first it checks for the `shapes` of arrays; if those are not same it returns `False`.

Comment: "But for `==` python must return a `bool` object" - what? Why do you say that?

Comment: It's a Python convention for this type of operator.  See my quote.

Comment: @user2357112 oops sorry it just was a writing mistake! thanks for reminding!